# 2014 Dodge Grand Caravan sporadic crank no starts

Tags: fuel-system, dodge, cranks-wont-run, grand-caravan

Good morning,

I have a 2014 Dodge Grand Caravan that occasionally has a crank/no start problem.

Occasionally, after sitting overnight, or for over an hour it will crank fine, but will not start for some time. I can hear the fuel pump priming, and once it starts (after a lot of cranking), it runs fine - no hesitation or loss of power. Other times it starts fine after sitting.

My first inclination is to replace the fuel pump, but it seems odd that there is no other symptoms.

Are there any things I should test, or other potential issues aside from the fuel pump?

Thanks!
Ben

Comment: If the car eventually starts, I wouldn't look first to the pump. Does it ever have problems starting while hot?

Comment: To narrow a crank, no-start problem, you'll have to determine whether its a spark or fuel issue. If there's a fuel test valve on the fuel rail, borrow a fuel pressure gauge from Autozone or Advance Auto and connect it; just turn on ignition, no starting. Pressure should come up immediately and remain high after engine startup. Spark testing requires at least one spark plug removed, plug wire reconnected, plug base grounded to engine block while someone cranks the engine; observe for spark. Plugs ever replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a faulty ASD relay